# Keep getting "'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'" Even though I clearly set an entity :\

Tags: objective-c, core-data

And yes, I've set up all the proper entities in my xcdatamodelId. I've been using CoreData for months now and have never run into this problem just yet. Is there something else I'm possible missing?

This is my code to pull data.

```
- (NSArray *)getCDRuneSets {
NSError *error;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Rune" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *cdRuneSets = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

return cdRuneSets;
}
```

And I have an entity named "Rune" in my xcdatamodelId. Any ideas on what I could possibly be doing wrong? :\

Edit:
I also have my AppDelegate run this piece of code to instantiate the my CoreDataBank's (It's a StaticSingleton) context

```
CoreDataBank *bank = [CoreDataBank getBank];
[bank setContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

Comment: Check the model being used by the context, to ensure it has the entity defined: use `NSLog(@"Model is %@",context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel);` and look through the output to check the entity is properly defined.

Comment: Have you verified that the context is actually not nil when you try to fetch?

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for all the ideas, yes, the entity was right and the context wasn't nil either. It turns out I forgot to initialize my FetchRequest :\ my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to this incase anyone finds it... Make sure your entity name in your model matches your specified entity in `entityForName`

I had an `s` in my model (as in plural) and not in my code :(